# Read excel in html format

Tags: .net, html, excel

I have an excel File which has sub-script and super script in it. When I save it in HTML format, I can see that they are embedded within 'sub' and 'sup' tags respectively.

What I want to do is, read the content of excel file, so that I can show the text with super/sub scripts on my report. I can read HTML, but want to know how can I convert the content of excel to HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

You may be experienciencing an urelated problem because subscripts in html and excel are compatible.

Here you have an example:

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks, but the example isn't complete I believe.

Comment: Please suggest what do you consider a "complete example", so others may help you. Or refine your description, as after reading it, I thought the above example was not working for you.

Comment: I was able to see only 'alt textalt text' in the example part, hence thought it wasn't complete. I can see the super/sub scripts in Excel. When I read them through VB.Net, they appear as normal strings without super/sub strings. I need to differentiate between normal text and super/sub script from the content of Excel.

Comment: @Shiva although you tagged your question .net, you are not clear enough in the question text. Please post which methods are you using to read the file

Comment: @Belisarius Thanks for your responses. I resolved the problem by saving the excel file as html programmitically in VB.Net. Then I was able to read the html tags and retrieve the super/sub scripts, to save them into a temporary storage(DB) so that I can use this to generate the report.